# Using of has_one association for model with encrypted primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, encryption, has-one

I have `Address` and `ZipCode` models. `Address` model has `encrypted_post_code` field, `ZipCode` has `code` field. I would like to tie `Address` records and `ZipCode` records with help of has_one association using specified fields. Currently I need it to use such ActiveRecords features as includes, preload, eager_load, etc.

Unfortunately all string fields of address records are encrypted (it's requirement of customer). I cannot use `has_one :zip_code, primary_key: :post_code, foreign_key: :code`, because I don't have post_code field in addresses table, it contains only encrypted_post_code field.

Please advise how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your customer actually understands the benefits of encryption.  But, it doesn't matter because your database should make associations by `id` rather than the encrypted postcode.

So, your zipcode table could have the columns `id, encrypted_post_code` and then an address just has a `postcode_id` field, and makes the join that way.  This way you avoid dealing with the encrypted postcodes completely, until you need to find out what the real postcode is, at which point you look it up via the association and decrypt it.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, it will work, but is there a way to not change tables' schemes? It will be quite painful.

Comment: Just change it with a migration, better to spend a little time getting it right now than to struggle on forever with something weird and unintuitive.